# Java does not work in my terminal on my IMac

Tags: java, macos, terminal

Every time I try to type in any command that starts with 'java' in my Mac's terminal I get the output:

```
-bash: java: command not found
```

and I don't know how to fix this... I've called apple.. I've googled for days and I can't find the answer to this frustrating problem

Comment: have you installed the jdk?

Comment: yes but I don't know why the command still doesn't work

Comment: what directories are on your path?

Comment: can you inform me how to check this I am brand new to computers

Comment: type `echo $PATH` in your terminal

Comment: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: when you install java there is usually a binary installed in `/usr/bin` which is on your path.  so you might try installing again.  How are you installing?  with the binary from oracle?

Comment: can you send me the link to the correct java jdk ?

Comment: here are the docs for JDK 8 install straight from oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

Comment: what do I do from that page?

Comment: read it and follow the instructions

Comment: here is the jdk8 image http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u51-b16/jdk-8u51-macosx-x64.dmg

Comment: did you tell me to do this to install it or uninstall it?

Comment: I found an answer on StackDifferent, does this help? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/165022/problem-with-installing-java-java-command-not-found

Comment: I completed all of the steps and Java still makes my terminal output

Comment: -bash: java: command not found

Comment: @DizzyCode thank you for the response but I have already visited that answer in my search for a goof one so I still have this probelm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/usr/libexec/java_home` to find where you JDK installed. Then set the PATH with it like this.

export JAVA_HOME="The value `/usr/libexec/java_home` shows"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you still have to add it to path. you can try this `export PATH=$PATH:xxx`(xxx is what you get from `/usr/libexec/java_home`). Or you can try `export PATH = $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` (Not quite sure if this can work, you can have a try).